# Laravel Image Uploading Issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, file-upload, laravel-6

Hello I'm trying to upload user photo in my laravel app,

When the user updating his/her profile user can add a propic.

The Problem

Now when I run my current code, If the user trying to update profile without uploading a photo, it gives me error saying

"**Call to a member function extension() on null**"

But when I try to upload a photo, **photo get uploaded successfully** but the **image name not storing in the DB (null value saved instead of image name)** and **other fields won't GET UPDATED.**

Here is my user profile update controller code (Only the function is included)

```
public function update(Request $request, User $setting)
        {

            $changedAttributes = array_diff($request->all(), $setting->getAttributes());

            $validationRules = array_intersect_key([
               'name'      => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
               'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:5', 'max:255'],
               'mobile'    => ['required', 'string', 'regex:/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
               2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
               4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/'],
               'email'     => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,'.$setting->id.''],
               'propic' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
           ], $changedAttributes);

           $imageName = time().'.'.$request->propic->extension();  

           $request->propic->move(public_path('propics'), $imageName);

           $this->validate($request, $validationRules);

           $setting->update($changedAttributes);

           return Redirect::back()->with('success',__('sentence.User updated successfully'));  

        }
```

And following is my form,

```
<form action="{{ route('settings.update',$user->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="/img/blank_user.png" alt="Profile Pic" style="border-radius: 100px;height: 150px;width: 150px; opacity: 0.5;" id="profile_pic_display">
            <input type="file" name="propic" class="form-control">  
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
            <!-- <form action="{{ route('settings.update',$user->id) }}" method="POST"> -->
            @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

                                <div class="form-group field-user-firstname required">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="user-firstname">{{ __('sentence.First Name') }}</label>
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{$user->name}}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group field-user-lastname required">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="user-lastname">{{ __('sentence.Last Name') }}</label>
                                    <input id="last_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="last_name" value="{{$user->last_name}}" required autocomplete="last_name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                                </div>                    
                            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group field-user-mobile required">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="user-mobile">{{ __('sentence.Mobile') }}</label>
                                    <input id="mobile" type="text" class="form-control @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror" name="mobile" value="{{$user->mobile}}" required autocomplete="mobile" autofocus>

                                @error('mobile')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group field-user-email required">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="user-email">{{ __('sentence.Email') }}</label>
                                    <input id="email_" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
                    <div class="pull-right form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{ __('sentence.Cancel') }}</button>     
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('sentence.Update') }}</button>       
                    </div>
        </div>
                        </div>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I able to found a solution for my above stated problem, 
I changed my controller function as stated in the below and made no change in the form,

```
public function update(Request $request, User $setting)
        {

            $changedAttributes = array_diff($request->all(), $setting->getAttributes());

            $validationRules = array_intersect_key([
               'name'      => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
               'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:5', 'max:255'],
               'mobile'    => ['required', 'string','min:10','max:14', 'regex:/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
               2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
               4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/'],
               'email'     => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,'.$setting->id.''],
               'propic' => ['required','image','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg','max:2048'],
           ], $changedAttributes);

           if($request->hasFile('propic'))
           {
                $this->validate($request, [
                    'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
                    'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:5', 'max:255'],
                    'mobile' => ['required', 'string','min:10','max:14', 'regex:/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
                    2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
                    4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/'],
                    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,'.$setting->id.''],
                    'propic' => ['required','image','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg','max:2048'],
                ],$request->all());

                $imageName = time().'.'.$request->propic->extension();  
                $request->propic->move(public_path('propics'), $imageName);
                $setting->propic=$imageName;
                $setting->name=$request->input('name');
                $setting->last_name=$request->input('last_name');
                $setting->mobile=$request->input('mobile');
                $setting->email=$request->input('email');
                $setting->update();
                return Redirect::back()->with('success',__('User updated successfully'));  
           }

           $this->validate($request, $validationRules);

           $setting->update($changedAttributes);

           return Redirect::back()->with('success',__('User updated successfully'));  

        }
```

So this has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
$imageName = time().'.'.$request->propic->extension();
```

To these

```
$imageName = time().'.'.$request->propic->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Comment: nope, error, Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Comment: @VolkaDimitrev can you remove this line `<!-- <form action="{{ route('settings.update',$user->id) }}" method="POST"> -->` and try again if it works? Or try to put `dd(request()->all())` at the first inside the `update` function and give me what it prints.

Comment: done the both, but still giving the same error, Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Comment: show the store function  how you are storing the image it is important  then I can help you